# Is Microsoft visual source code safety on my code

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

In many times, Microsoft visual source has **removed** files from my solution after a check-in for the whole solution. especially when I work in offline-mode for a while and then  reconnect and check-in.

My question:
Is it really safety to my code ?

You may will laugh, I always copy the code to a backup folder before make any check in for many projects in the solution.

Note: I work on my own with the solution [Not in team], I use it just for *backup* and version history.

Any idea, help!!

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Source Safe is better than having nothing at all, however, has many [problems](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html) and is seen as [unreliable](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html) by [many](http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html).

Do yourself a favor and move yourself to either [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or a distributed SCM like [Git](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgit-scm.com%2F&rct=j&q=git&ei=AfMETcXYGceZhQfvypjuBw&usg=AFQjCNHBOAWIJWLQ6wmj_GErAgGzWCkTbA&cad=rja) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

I have seen VSS databases get corrupted, though the biggest issue with it is when working with a team and the locking nature of the program (only one person can work on a file at one time).

Comment: Mercurial rocks and it's dead simple.  You can have Mercurial be you own source control until you are ready to push it to VSS and all your changes will get pushed into VSS with comments as well.  Maybe you should google how to do that as well.

Comment: The locking of files can be an advantage. I've been using SVN in a team for four years now, but must files have been given the 'needs-lock' property to introduce the locking here too. Some files are hard to merge and merging slows down the process and can introduce errors. In most cases, developers can wait or go do something else when someone else is making a small change to a file. This of course depends on the size of the team (which is 1, in the OP's case) and the number of times people need to edit the exact same files, which in turn depends on the size and nature of the project.

Comment: @GolezTrol - Of course locking makes less (no?) difference in a team of 1, however if _all_ your files are using locking, it slows the team down.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot said about Visual Source Safe, but its main problem is that it's not so powerful and versatile as other version control systems. I've worked with SourceSafe for many years and it has always worked perfectly, except for one co-worker who also had problems checking in files. Usually this was because he was making errors like not checking out files in which case they couldn't be checked in as well. When he started fooling around making copies back and forth to fix his problems, things could go wrong. But you got these kinds of problems with many other systems too. I'm using SVN, which can give you a hard time when you need to merge files. 
But for a single person's version control it should work fine. I'm guessing you're doing something wrong.